# Cannot find symbol when calling a method

Tags: java, methods

I have two seperate java files, but both in the same folder, so calling methods should be easy. The problem is here;

```
    paDelimo = nota.vrniOktavo() + nota.vrniIndeks() + this.razmak * indeks;
```

Here it says cannot find symbol. It tells me that something is wrong with the **nota.vrniOktavo()** call What it does, is, it calls for a method in the other Java file. I have no idea why it doesnt work?

What should the call be like? It is calling for the method, included in this code, below. Below this code, you will also find the whole code for the file which the problematic line belongs to.

```
  public class Nota{
private int oktava;
private int indeks;



public Nota(int oktava, int indeks){
    this.oktava = oktava;
    this.indeks = indeks;
}

public int vrniOktavo(){
    return this.oktava;
}

public int vrniIndeks(){
    return this.indeks;
}
}
```

And here is the rest of the code, coming from the part that does not work;

```
public class Lestvica{

private int razmak;
private Nota zacetnaNota;


public Lestvica(Nota zacetnaNota, int razmak){
    this.zacetnaNota = zacetnaNota;
    this.razmak = razmak;
}
 public Nota clen(int indeks){
    int paDelimo = 0;
    int dobljenaOktava = 0;
    int dobljeniIndeks = 0;

    paDelimo = nota.vrniOktavo() + nota.vrniIndeks() + this.razmak * indeks;

    dobljenaOktava = paDelimo / 12;
    dobljeniIndeks = paDelimo % 12;
    Nota drugaNota = new Nota(dobljenaOktava, dobljeniIndeks);
    return drugaNota;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are wanting to call zacetnaNota, not nota, in the Lestvica class.

Here is the fixed code:

```
public class Lestvica {

private int razmak;
private Nota zacetnaNota;

public Lestvica(Nota zacetnaNota, int razmak) {
    this.zacetnaNota = zacetnaNota;
    this.razmak = razmak;
}

public Nota clen(int indeks) {
    int paDelimo = 0;
    int dobljenaOktava = 0;
    int dobljeniIndeks = 0;

    paDelimo = zacetnaNota.vrniOktavo() + zacetnaNota.vrniIndeks() + this.razmak * indeks;

    dobljenaOktava = paDelimo / 12;
    dobljeniIndeks = paDelimo % 12;
    Nota drugaNota = new Nota(dobljenaOktava, dobljeniIndeks);
    return drugaNota;
}
```

Comment: Awsome, i changed the nota to zacetnaNota and it works fine! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

`nota` is undifined. You have an instance of `Nota` which is named `zacetnaNota`, therefore you should write:

```
paDelimo = zacetnaNota.vrniOktavo() + zacetnaNota.vrniIndeks() + this.razmak * indeks;
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that of an undeclared variable.

In the method

```
public Nota clen(int indeks){
    int paDelimo = 0;
    int dobljenaOktava = 0;
    int dobljeniIndeks = 0;

    paDelimo = nota.vrniOktavo() + nota.vrniIndeks() + this.razmak * indeks;

    // code continues
}
```

you are trying to assign the variable `paDelimo` a value from the object named `nota`, which is not created or available in the scope of the method. The only instance of class `Nota` available in this class is `zacetnaNota`. But you are trying to read from `nota`.

So, if you've confused the name of the variable, rewrite the line as

```
paDelimo = zacetnaNota.vrniOktavo() + zacetnaNota.vrniIndeks() + this.razmak * indeks;
```

Or create another instance of the `Nota` class, named `nota`, to resolve the missing reference.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I figured it should be zacetnaNota instead of just "nota".

Comment: Z3br3 nota is the undelcared variable, you are wanting to change "nota" to "zacetnaNota". (Or, I am assuming that. Eclipse told me it was going unused).

Comment: Please accept the answer that you have found most helpful. by clicking on the check mark beside the answer. Cheers !!

Answer (score 2):

Or you can Implement getter for `zacetnaNota` :

```
private Nota zacetnaNota;

public Nota getZacetnaNota() {
    return zacetnaNota;
}
```

Then :

```
 paDelimo = getZacetnaNota().vrniOktavo() + getZacetnaNota().vrniIndeks() + this.razmak * indeks;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!